# Bigquery : Change Table's Partitioning

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an existing table partitioned by ingestion time (`_PARTITIONTIME`). That table got corrupted and I had to fix it by retrieving data from another table. The problem is that I now have nearly 95% of my data sharing the same `_PARTITIONTIME` (the date of the fix).
My data have a timestamp field `my_timestamp`, that could be used to have a correct partitioning.

But the other constraint I have is that there is multiple external connectors querying this table using the `_PARTITIONTIME` field and I want to avoid updating these queries.

I would like to alter the table such as, for every rows actually in the table, the `_PARTITIONTIME` has the value of `my_timestamp` field. And for the next rows appended in the table, the ingestion time is used.

Is it possible to do such thing ?

Comment: Have you tried this approach ?https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#creating_a_partitioned_table_from_the_result_of_a_query

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Actually it made me elaborate more on the question, and I found the answer on the way.
Sorry for the time lost.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, which was actually pretty simple but I post it here anyway in case someone else try over-complicated thing for such a simple use case.

```
UPDATE `MY_TABLE`
SET _PARTITIONTIME = my_timestamp
WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = [THE_FIX_DATE]
```

For some reason I expected the `_PARTITIONTIME` to be immutable but it is not.